# In VSCode extension, how to fill an untitled unsaved file with content read from another file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Using VSCode 1.61.2, I am making an extension that must open an empty, unsaved file in the editor.

The first part, without filling the document, is done like bellow, and works well:

```
vscode.workspace.openTextDocument({
    language: "json",
    content: "toto"
})
```

However, I would like the content to be filled with the content of a file located in the extension code source. The file is located at:

```
src/my-file.json
```

So far I have:

```
vscode.workspace.openTextDocument("src/my-file.json").then((file) => {
    vscode.workspace.openTextDocument({
        language: "json",
        content: file.getText()
    })
})
```

However, this throws:

> rejected promise not handled within 1 second: Error: cannot open
> file:///src/my-file.json. Detail: Unable to read file
> '\src\my-file.json' (Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file
> '\src\my-file.json')

I highly suspect the `workspace` refers to the user workspace, thus the file does not exist, which explain the error.

However, if I am right, I did not find anything in [the api](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api) that allows to read extension files.

How can I read my extension source files and write it into an empty unsaved file in the editor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the path in the extension

```
let srcfolder = path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'my-file.json');
```

Or use the [ExtensionContext](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionContext) that is the argument of the `activate` function, use the member `extensionUri` this is also web extension save, use `vscode.workspace.fs` to read the file

Comment: ``path.join(context.extensionPath, "src", "my-file.json")`` was the solution. Thanks.